# Mongo .get returning junk

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman

When I execute this function from something like Postman:

```
router.get('/db', function(req, res, next) {

    tune.find({}, function (err, results) {
        res.json(results);
    });

});
```

My database returns this:

```
[{"_id":"56f30425ba97bb301fe6ab1a","__v":0},    
{"_id":"56f30514f9b7ea3b1f1fd9f7","__v":0},    
{"_id":"56f306bb9c8203451f2cc58a","__v":0},
{"_id":"56f306ca9c8203451f2cc58b","__v":0},
{"_id":"56f306e99c8203451f2cc58c","__v":0},
{"_id":"56f33d43b64d540b208b6c3c","__v":0}]
```

My mongoose schema:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var track = new Schema({
    title: String,
    artist: String,
    genre: String
});
var tune = mongoose.model('tune', track);
```

My post:

```
router.post('/db', function(req, res, next) {
    var tune1 = new tune(req.body);
    tune1.save(function (err) {
        if (err) { console.log('error!');}
        else {
            res.json({message: 'Track successfully posted'});
        }
    });
});
```

Request Post:

```
app.use('/users', userRoutes);

var options = { method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/db',
    headers:
    { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'postman-token': '',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache' },
    form: { title: '000000', artist: 'blah blah', genre: 'rap' } };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);

    console.log(body);
});
```

When I do a post command from Postman I get a successful post message. Is it just the way I am returning the JSON? I want to be able to see title, artist, and genre for every post in the DB.

Thanks

Comment: Do a quick sanity check: get in to your database using `mongo` from the command line and execute that find command. I have an inkling Mongoose isn't saving your tunes right.

Comment: @TannerFaulkner That is a good idea. Still new to this though, can you offer some help on how to do that? I'm guessing I must be within the DB directory but whats the actual command? I can't just do .find can I?

Comment: MongoDB if fun. :) It's going to look a lot like your JS. Start by running `mongo` from a command line. Once you're connected to your local MongoDB, run `show dbs`. Find your database and select it by running `use MyDatabaseName`. Now let's check out our collections, `show collections`. You should see either tracks or tunes there. Run `db.tunes.find()`, or maybe `db.tracks.find()` to see what your node app has saved to the database so far.

Comment: tune1.save(callback);  inside your else statement and prior to your res.json({ message: ... }); might solve your problem. Let me know if it does, and I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @TannerFaulkner I ran those commands and db.tunes shows the same list as my original output from the DB. I guess this means there is a problem in my storing method rather than displaying correct?

Comment: @jmugz3 Callback isn't defined in my function. How should it be defined?

Comment: try it without a callback.  tune1.save();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance, Mongoose simply isn't saving what you're expecting. Try taking a look at `req.body` and `tune1` in a debugger to make sure you're getting the expected result.

It might also help to set `strict` to `'throw'` in your schema, just so we get an error back when we attempt to save an invalid `tune`:

```
var track = new Schema({
    title: String,
    artist: String,
    genre: String
}, {
    strict: 'throw'
});
```

Comment: You are right. req.body is undefined. If you can take a look at the edits I just added. I added where I actually call the post from. I can't figure out why body has nothing in it.

Comment: Got a body parser? https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser Express doesn't parse and populate `req.body` by default -- it's a separate module you'll need to `app.use` before anything that will be using `req.body`.

Comment: Also, take a look at [mocha](https://mochajs.org/) and [supertest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest) sometime after you sort this out. Your test function is really close to being a proper unit test.

Comment: The body parser worked thanks a lot! Now I'm getting output like: '{"_id":"56f42236548afeb024533706","title":"000000","artist":"blah blah","genre":"rap","__v":0}]'